# What else do I need to do to plug in jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am building a page using [jQuery UI tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/), and I am seeing some effect, but not what is intended. The UL used to store the tab headings is wired up so that the UL and tab contents are part of the same larger DIV. The console contains diagnostic info of some description, but no reported errors in my code, others' code, resource loading, etc. I've checked the links to JavaScript/CSS and they all point to real resources that look like JavaScript/CSS:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Averia+Serif+Libre:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom/jquery-ui.css' />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/bgstretch.js"></script>
```

The display, in terms of presentation one would expect of CSS, just what one would see without any attempt to apply jQuery UI. The debugger, however, does display added classes that one would expect of jQuery UI turning a UL and some DIVs into a tabbed display, for instance:

```
<a href="#living-room" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6">Living Room</a>
```

The original element is unadorned:

```
<a href="#living-room">Living Room</a>
```

What can / should I be doing so jQuery tabs are behaving normally?

Comment: Where's you complete HTML for the part you're trying to tabify?  The jQuery UI Tabs requires a very specific layout of the tab and contents for it to work properly.

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> are these two CDNs?

Comment: @jmoerdyk I was trying to follow jQuery UI's specific for tabbing. Minus a block of barely formatted text, it's at http://pastebin.com/PDhuFaC5 .

Comment: @DulyKinsky I was attempting to make two requests from one single jQuery umbrella CDN, homepage at http://code.jquery.com/.

Comment: And why are your jQuery UI css and js files from different versions?  Are your include paths correct?

Comment: when you look at your developer tools, do you receive the jquery, and query-ui js files?

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzxbqY

Did you include the jquery ui css?

I stripped out all your scripts and used

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

I included jquery then jquery ui, and 
[this](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css)

jquery ui css file.

Comment: It's there as the second `<link>` in the block, but it's referencing a different version of jQuery UI than the js `<script>`

Answer (score 0):

A working version is here (based on your code):

https://jsfiddle.net/g3o7chw1/1/

I think the issue may be the ui theme css. When I use the regular theme cdn it seems to work fine:
 `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your scripts CDN src link does not have the http protocol.
Instead of:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You should have:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems.  First, if the code you pasted is accurate, you have a problem in the call to the `ready()` method:

```
;(jQuery.ready(function()
{
    jQuery('#tabs').tabs();
}()));
```

which as you say doesn't produce any errors.  However, it doesn't do anything either!  Cleaning off superfluous parens and semicolons, your code looks like this:

```
jQuery.ready(function()
{
    jQuery('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

Now, the problem here is that you aren't saying what needs to be ready before you call the `tabs()` method, because you don't specify a selector that you're applying the `ready()` method to.  This means that your `tabs()` method never gets called.

With the `ready()` method, the selector should always be `document`.  So, if you change your code to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
{
    jQuery('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

you'll find that your `tabs()` function gets called.  You'll notice that JD E and John Detlefs substitute `$` for `jQuery`, which is common (nearly ubiquitous, in fact) shorthand, but otherwise this is how they have it as well.  This is the conventional way to call `ready()`.  (There are two equivalent syntaxes (yours isn't one of them) which you can read about [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).)

Your second problem appears to be a compatibility issue: your directory structure suggests that you are using jquery-ui.js v. 1.11.4 and jquery-ui.css v. 1.12.0.  If so, you will definitely have problems, because 1.12.0 implemented a lot of breaking changes.  Have a look at [this document](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#general-changes).  In it, in the section under tabs, you'll find this:

> The tabs widget now adds the ui-tabs-tab class instead of the inconsistently named ui-tab to each tab element.

If you in fact have the different versions of the .js and .css files suggested by your directory structure, you'll probably have the .js file applying a `ui-tab` class, and the .css file looking for classes with `ui-tabs-tab`.  So you won't get the styling, unless they put in backward compatibility.  Which they haven't in some cases.  (Update: looking at the link that JD E provides in his answer, I don't see any evidence of this change.  There are several references to `ui-tab` and none to `ui-tabs-tab`.  Since 1.12.0 was only released three weeks ago, maybe it's a documented change that never actually occurred, and they haven't had time to undocument it yet.  But I'd still get my versions consistent if I were you.)

I would suggest that you make sure that your jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css files are the same version.  If you don't need to support IE, I'd suggest going to 1.12.0.  If you do, then you'll need to research which versions of jQuery UI support which versions of IE.  (1.12.0 dropped support of IE 10 and older versions.)  Also, your version of jquery.js is three years old at this point and you might consider upgrading.  The latest version is now 3.1.0 (recently released), 2.2.4 has been around for a while.